# pg_restore: [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid archive

Tags: postgresql

i backup local database use

```
pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -W -F t test_db > .\local-11-06.tar
```

then i drop test_db and recreate by

```
CREATE DATABASE test_db ENCODING 'UTF8'
```

then restore by pg_restore

```
pg_restore -h localhost -U postgres -p 5432 --dbname=test_db --verbose .\local-11-06.tar
```

but error with

```
pg_restore: [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid archive
```

**What might be wrong?**
(my PC info : windows 10 with postgresql 11)

---

P.S.

it is work on CMD but failed on PowerShell.(Encoding? i'm in JP)

Comment: That would be a bug. Is the file a valid TAR file, that is, can you unpack the archive?

Comment: @Laurenz Albe seem the file is not a valid TAR file. ` tar xvf local-11-06.tar` error with `tar: This does not look like a tar archive`

Comment: Works for me here on Linux.  Questions: 1) Where did you get Postgres from? 2) Are you using the same version to do the `pg_dump` and `pg_restore`?  3) What happens if you use a simpler file name(without `\`), say test_out.tar? Add answers as update to your question.

Comment: Are you really sure you used `pg_dump -F t` to generate this? What does `file \local-11-06.tar` give you?

Comment: it is work on CMD but failed on PowerShell.(Encoding? i'm in JP)